# How to call one directory tempate file in to other template file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cross-sells, popup

how to call app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\crosssell.phtml to app\code\local\Cmsmart\AjaxCart\controllers\IndexController\ in popup window

```
    if(@$product) $json_encode['ajaxcontinue'] = '
    <div>
        <ul class="messages ajaxcart-messages">
            <li class="success-msg">
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a title="'.@$product->getName().'" href="'.@$product->getProductUrl().'">'.@$product->getName().' </a> '.$this->__('has been added to cart').'.</span></li>
                    <li><button onclick="setLocation(\''.Mage::getBaseUrl().'checkout/\')" class="button btn-continue" title="'.$this->__('Checkout').'" type="button"><span><span>'.$this->__('Checkout').'</span></span></button>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Call below code in popup it will load same phtml for you

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->‌​setTemplate('checkou‌​t/cart/crosssell.pht‌​ml')->setProduct($pr‌​oduct)->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: i got error like, " syntax error, unexpected 'checkout' (T_STRING) in app\code\local\Cmsmart\AjaxCart\controllers\IndexController.php on line 114"

Comment: this module work only with checkout page , By the way where you are trying to fetch this block

Comment: that is my question i want to fetch block from other block, there is option for that

Comment: For that you need to set product i think I am not sure its working or not but you can try `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml')->setProduct($product)->toHtml();?>`

Comment: Where you create your popup ? At that place put this peice of code and your job is done